# redirect index.html to root aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, gatsby

I have a static gatsby site hosted on AWS S3 and Cloudfront and I'm trying to redirect all instances of index.html to the root url "/". I tried doing this with gatsby createRedirect from "/index.html" to "/" along w AWS S3 routing rules, but it's not working as expected. The redirecting tool I use (http://www.redirect-checker.org/) notices there's a redirect, but the redirect it finds is from mysite.com/index.html to mysite.com/index.html, but I set up the rules from "/index.html" to "/". Is there a way to fix this so the response is still a 301 redirect, but to the root url instead of index.html?

Comment: Did you add the Default Root Object in the cloudfront for the distribution

Comment: @Ali yes I did it's still the same. when i got to mywebsite.com/index.html the redirect-checker shows it's redirected to mywebsite.com/index.html and not the root :(

Comment: One you have index object specificied in cloudfront remove all the redirect and cloudfront will take care of it

Comment: @Ali hmm still not working. I mean before it was already automatically redirecting from /index.html to the root; the problem is that when I use a redirect checker tool it shows that the redirect is to /index.html, but I want that redirected to the root.

Comment: Still not working can you please what is happening or can post the link?

Comment: Ok so initially, I created a redirect request from '/index.html' to '/'. When I check for the redirect status of mywebsite.com/index.html the status code checker shows there is a 301 redirect request but the destination of the request is the same as the origin (/index.html). Same goes for when I check the redirect status for mywebsite.com/ (without the /index.html) it also shows a 301 status code with the destination being same as origin (/).

Comment: in S3 bucket properties have you mentioned the Index document as index.html ... Also comment the gatsby redirect

Comment: sorry yes did everything and nothing still working :/

Comment: @keithp96 Did you managed to get the redirect working from index.html to root? Can you describe the settings in CloudFront and redirect rule in the S3 bucket, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by looking at your settings in CloudFront when creating your distribution. You'll see a setting 'Default Root Object'.

The object that you want CloudFront to return (for example, index.html) when a viewer request points to your root URL (http://www.example.com) instead of to a specific object in your distribution (http://www.example.com/index.html).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html